# Deriving Feynman rules from Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

On my notes I have written this *"method to obtain Feynman rules from the Lagrangian"* but I can't find it anywhere else (books, internet) so I'm starting to doubt it is a general method.

The method is $$\text{FD with ext particles } \chi_a\chi_b\chi_c\dots =\frac{\delta^{(n)}i\mathcal{L}}{\delta\chi_a\delta\chi_b\delta\chi_c\dots}$$ with the "appropriate lagrangian term", and the provided example is the QED vertex: $$\Gamma_\mu=\frac{\delta^{(3)}i\mathcal{L}}{\delta A_\mu\delta\psi\delta\bar\psi}=\frac{\delta^{(3)}}{\delta A_\mu\delta\psi\delta\bar\psi}\left[i\bar\psi i (-ieA_\nu\gamma^\nu)\psi\right]=ie\delta_{\mu\nu}\gamma^\nu=ie\gamma_\mu$$ which seems right. My question is: **is this method correct in general? Maybe only for vertices and not for propagators?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at my personal notes and I've found a somewhat related principle, and only for vertices, not propagators (but unfortunately I don't know the source of these notes...) :

Let $T^n_{S_I}[\{\phi_i\}_i]$ be a term in the interaction action involving $n$ fields. Express it as an inverse Fourier transform of the fields $\phi_i$. You then have $T^n_{S_I}[\{\tilde{\phi}_i\}_i]$. Then the vertex is given by:
\begin{equation}
V=\frac{i\delta^n T^n_{S_I}[\{\tilde{\phi}_i\}_i]}{\delta \tilde{\phi}_1 \cdots \delta\tilde{\phi}_{i_\text{max}}}.
\end{equation}

As an example let $T^n_{S_I}[\{\phi_i\}_i]$ be $T^3_{S_I}[\overline{\Psi},\Psi,A]=-e\int d^4x\, \overline{\Psi} \gamma^\mu \Psi A_\mu$. It is easy to show that the vertex $V^\rho$ is:
\begin{equation}
V^\rho = \frac{i \delta^3 T^3_{S_I}[\overline{\Psi},\Psi,A]}{\delta \widetilde{\overline{\Psi}}(p_1)\delta \widetilde{\Psi}(p_2) \delta \widetilde{A}_\rho (p_3)}=-ie\gamma^\rho \delta^{(4)}(p_1+p_2+p_3).
\end{equation}
Where the three momenta are oriented toward the center of the vertex, and the delta is here to ensure momentum conservation.
A good exercise is to find the four-gluon vertex with this short method.

Your method is essentially the same but the fact that you use the Lagrangian density and not the action means that you are automatically in momentum representation.

Comment: On a side note, I don't think one can come up with a simple recipe for propagator by looking at the Lagrangian, right? Finding the propagator, even in momentum space, needs inverting non-trivial matrices.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Yes you are right, in general, there is no simple recipe, even in momentum space. There are of course trivial examples where it is possible, but in general, it would be kind of a superpower to deduce the propagator just by looking at the Lagrangian density.